# Malloc within function not changing pointer value

Tags: c, pointers, memory, malloc

So when I pass a data type like a struct to assign some memory to it I find that the pointer doesn't change within the main scope. This further becomes a problem when I try to free the memory but obviously if its using the original pointer it will be pointing at the stack address.

```
void allocate(int *value){
    value = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
}

int main(){
    int val2;

    allocate(&val2);

    free(&val2);

    return 0;
}
```

I can fix this by using a double pointer to be passed into the allocate function but some course work I'm doing requires to only pass a pointer and I cant get it to update the pointer when it returns to main. I have looked around for a while but cant find a straight forward answer, I feel like my coursework is wrong but that might be my lack of understanding.

Comment: Uh, problems here. There is no pointer variable in your main to change. And there is no reason to pass the address of val2 to allocate(), it has no use for it. Once you actually have a pointer variable in main(), you could pass its address (the double pointer you mentioned) to allocate(), or you could set it to a value that you would modify allocate() to return.

Comment: Okay, so I'm assuming that the address being passed to allocate is just a copy and I'm just updating a copy value of it therefore not changing the memory address at all. The big issue I'm having is that in the test suite which I cannot modify the function is being called just as shown above but with a struct, since this struct is not a pointer is that still the same issue? @AviBerger

Comment: Are you by any chance passing a pointer to an existing struct (so there is already memory of the struct itself) and initializing members of the struct instance that are pointers to newly allocated memory? That would be different than your post. In that case, you aren't trying to modify the incoming pointer, but what it points to, which was created before the fcn call.

Comment: @AviBerger Yes I believe that is correct and that I have misunderstood what I was assigned to do and so I have asked a pretty misleading question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement to "only pass a pointer" seems contrived, and you could argue that a pointer to pointer (not a "double pointer") *is* a pointer, but perhaps you could use `void *` to punch a hole in the type system.  Or use a struct:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct intbuffer {
    int *d;
    size_t cap;
};


void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
    void *r = malloc(s);
    if( r == NULL ){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }
    return r;
}

void
allocate(void *p, size_t s)
{
    *(int **)p = xmalloc(s * sizeof(int));
}

void
allocate2(struct intbuffer *p)
{
    p->d = xmalloc(p->cap * sizeof *p->d);
}


int
main(void)
{
    int *val2;
    struct intbuffer v;

    allocate(&val2, 10);
    free(val2);

    v.cap = 10;  /* Horrible api!! */
    allocate2(&v);
    free(v.d);

    return 0;
}
```

Note that setting the capacity in the struct prior to making the call to allocate is a violation of many principles of software design, but this whole thing is absurdly contrived due to the bizarre artificial limitations.

Comment: I think that you have helped me clear up a misconception with my course work as I'm assuming they want me to actually allocate the values within the struct than the struct itself. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are not enough *'s in each place, but you will have to figure out what that means.

```
void allocate(int** value){
    *value = malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
}

int main(){
    int* val2;

    allocate(&val2);

    free(val2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I appropriate the help, I understand that this is a solution as I mentioned I can fix it with a double pointer, but I was wondering if there is another solution due to the coursework setup I've been given is to pass a struct (not struct pointer) and give it memory with malloc.